# Is the usage of "at" correct in this case? Should it go with "where" or "which"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Can someone tell me whether we should use "at" when we use where:

> The design is so unified and everything is at where they should be.

Or it must be like the one below:

> The design is so unified and everything is at which they should be.

Also please check the sentences below and tell me whether they are correct.

> The design is so unified and everything is located at where they should be.
>
> The design is so unified and everything is located at which they should be.

Comment: I tried to correct your question as better as I could. I changed the title to make it clearer to those who browse the questions. Hope it still works for your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid none is correct. You don't need any preposition in that sentence. You could simply write:

> *The design is so unified and everything is where it should be.*

Note that I changed from "*they*" to "*it*", because that pronoun refers to "*everything*" which is singular.

Regarding your edit, I'd say that it's still incorrect. Is there a reason why you need the preposition? If you use it, your sentence only gets more wordy. If you really want to add some other term there, you could write:

- "*...and everything is  positioned where it should be.*"
- "*...and everything is located where it should be.*"

It still sounds too wordy if compared to the example I gave above, but I also wrote them to show you that even in this case, there is no preposition. Finally, making a quick search of "*...and everything is located at where it should be.*" gave me no results at all.

Comment: What if I said `"The design is so unified and everything is located at where it should be."`

Comment: I'll write it in my answer.

Comment: @Braveyard The main point is that the idea of "at" is already a part of "where".  "Where" basically means "at which place," so you really don't ever need *at* and *where* together.

Comment: Thanks Lettuce but Alenanno, you haven't mentioned `at which`. Were they correct?

Comment: @Braveyard: In that case, it would be incorrect also without preposition, because "where" expresses the _location_, "which" doesn't. :)

Comment: I would also take issue with the word "so", which seems to be just a clumsy attempt to intensify "unified". Substituting the more grammatically valid intensifier "very" simply reveals it to be vacuous vebosity, in my opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I didn't notice it before but... Is it  incorrect or just informal and/or nonstandard? It reminds me of expressions like "This is so beautiful!"

Comment: @Alenanno: I wouldn't like to say "so" is actually "incorrect" here. But you're right - it's being used by OP to mean "very", as in your example. For me, it comes across as being a bit sloppy/informal. Personally I'd scrap the whole sentence and just say **The design is fully integrated**. I don't know what this designed thing actually *is*, but I doubt it really means much to say of it that "everything is in its optimum place" anyway. Sounds like ad-speak to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I honestly intentionally ignored the meaning of the sentence and just focused on the part that was being asked. But I agree, it's not the best way to write it.

Comment: @Alenanno: Phrasing aside, I think OP's core problem here is that *in principle* "unified design" (taking account of *all* functional requirements within the initial design) and "integrated design" (ensuring that all components are optimally distributed and interconnected) are two different aspects of good design. But in practice these are subtleties to take account of *while doing the design*. They're not likely to be seen as two distinct advantages when you're trying to talk up the design to others, *after* implementation.